# fast regex match excluding certain words

Tags: regex

I have the following regex pattern to find an email address in my code:

```
/[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]{8,}/i
```

I want to make sure it does not match a certain string if it includes:

```
abc
xyz
```

Just to exclude the abc I have tried:

```
/(?!.*abc)[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]{8,}/i
```

But that is horribly slow.

Comment: Do you have to do it in a single regexp?

Comment: BTW, you don't need to escape `.` inside `[]`

Comment: `But that is horribly slow` ... how are you measuring speed/performance here?  A single negative lookahead should not drag down performance so much, I think.

Comment: Are you using this to find an email address anywhere in the text, or to test a string to see if it's a valid email? If you're using it to find, the negative lookahead is testing the entire input, not just the email part.

Comment: @Barmar: No, but unless you have PHP code for me, I don't know how to do it in 2 steps without making it too complex.

Regex is used to find AN email address in the text. Not to see if a string is a valid email address.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: Without that lookahead exclusion it runs for somewhere between 3 - 5 seconds. The expanded regex takes more than 30 seconds before I abort it. The performance decreases so bad, that a look with 'the naked eye' is enough to determine this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "anchor" the regex to a position that can be found by the regex engine in an optimal way. The best way is to "tie" it to a word boundary position, and that should work here since emails start with word chars:

```js
/\b(?!\S*abc)[\w.-]+@[\w.-]{8,}/i
```

BTW, `[_a-zA-Z0-9]` is equal to `\w` in JavaScript regex. *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!\S*abc)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are zero or more non-whitespace chars and then `abc` immediately to the right of the current location
- `[\w.-]+` - one or more word, `.` or `-` chars
- `@` - a `@` char
- `[\w.-]{8,}`- eight  or more word, `.` or `-` chars.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor Stribizew that worked and thanks for the explanation.

Just to make sure, is it best practice if I also want to xyz I turn 
(?!\S*abc)
into
(?!\S*(abc|xyz))
?

Comment: @Rick Yes, that is fine, you may also use a non-capturing group, `(?:abc|xyz)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two steps. Use a regular expression to find the email address, then check that it doesn't contain any of the prohibited strings.

```
if (preg_match('/[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]{8,}/i', $text, $match) && !preg_match('/abc|xyz/i', $match[0])) {
    $email = $match[0];
}
```